# Next.js access environment variable in _app.js file

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, storyblok

I am building a blog using Storyblok (v2) and Next.js (v13). I understand that NEXT_PUBLIC environment variables can be exposed to the browser, and I do not want my access token exposed. I have used the api folder in the past to accomplish this in component files, but I do not think that I can use that for the page files—unless I am wrong. I have read the documentation from Next.js, and I am confused as to how I can accomplish this in my `_app.js` file. I am still learning about how to properly hide these using Next.js, and I was successful in my previous attempt.

This is what I have tried so far after searching for answers. I have added my access token to a `.env` file in the root of my project. I did not use `NEXT_PUBLIC`. I left that off because in my other project where I was able to hide my environment variables from the browser, that is how I did it. I also added it to my `next.config.js` file based on the information that I found in my search. This is what that file looks like:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  env: { ACCESS_TOKEN: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

My `_app.js` file looks like this:

```
import { storyblokInit, apiPlugin } from '@storyblok/react'
import '../styles/globals.css'

storyblokInit({
  accessToken: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
  use: [apiPlugin],
});

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Of course the above does not work. When I add `{process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN}` to any page, it is showing the token. I understand why this does not work based on the docs that I read, but I just wanted to try everything that I could before posting my question here.

Prior to doing these things, I also tried adding my variable to the `.env` file in the root of my project (not using the `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix), and then in my `_app.js` file, I had the following:

```
import { storyblokInit, apiPlugin } from '@storyblok/react'
import '../styles/globals.css'

storyblokInit({
  accessToken: token,
  use: [apiPlugin],
});

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp

function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: {
      token: props.env.ACCESS_TOKEN
    }
  }
}
```

My `next.config.js` file wasn't touched, so it did not contain `env` in it. The error that I get is that token is not defined. [This](https://plainenglish.io/blog/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-next-js) article is where I found the steps that I attempted.

I started using trial and error after that—mainly because I went down the Google rabbit hole and got super frustrated. This was my Hail Mary:

```
import { storyblokInit, apiPlugin } from '@storyblok/react'
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, props }) {
  storyblokInit({
    accessToken: props.token,
    use: [apiPlugin],
  });

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp

function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: {
      token: props.env.ACCESS_TOKEN
    }
  }
}
```

The error that I get here is: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'token')`

Is what I am trying to do even possible in the `_app.js` file? I am happy to read any other documentation that I may not have found in my search if that is a better response to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the calls in every page as ISR or SSR sending Storyblok API key in request as Token header instead of using storyblockInit.
Ie: index.js would have it's own call.